# How to statically get TypeVar parameters from a Generic for use in static type checking?

Tags: python, generics, mypy, static-typing, python-typing

I have a class that inherits from `typing.Generic` and passes in one `TypeVar` as the parameter.

Later on in the code, I would like to:

1. Statically (not at runtime) get the `TypeVar` parameter out from the class
2. Alias it to another type variable
3. Use that alias to type hint the `return` of a function

Is there some way in Python that I can make this happen?

The only piece I am missing is step 1, how to get the type parameter out of a type variable

---

**My Use Case**

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import TypeVar, Generic


TFloat = TypeVar("TFloat", bound=float)


class BaseDataClass(Generic[TFloat], ABC):

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def data(self) -> TFloat:
        """Get data."""


class ChildDataClass(BaseDataClass[int]):

    @property
    def data(self) -> int:
        return 1
```

I then import `BaseDataClass` and `ChildDataClass` into another module.

In that second module, is there some way to statically get the `TFloat` parameter from `BaseDataClass`, or the `int` parameter from `ChildDataClass`, and use it in `mypy`?

FYI: I am using Python 3.8.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way of "getting" out a type variable. You shouldn't think of a type variable as being like a chunk of data you can potentially extract somehow. Instead, think of it as a part of a definition.

I think based on your question, what you're really after is a way of writing a function that accepts some `BaseDataClass[T]` (or a subclass of this type) and returns whatever `T` is.

If so, create a function that *matches* the definition of whatever you want to accept. But instead of specifying that the inner type must be something specific, capture it using a generic instead.

In this case, we chose to match against anything of type `BaseDataClass[T]`, where we keep T generic. And our return type will be whatever T happened to match up against.

```py
from typing import TypeVar
from other_module import BaseDataClass, ChildDataClass

T = TypeVar('T', bound=float)

def extract(wrapper: BaseDataClass[T]) -> T:
    return wrapper.data


# BaseDataClass[FloatSubclass] exactly matches against BaseDataClass[T],
# and so T will be FloatSubclass in 'extract(x)' call.

class FloatSubclass(float): pass
x: BaseDataClass[FloatSubclass]
reveal_type(extract(x))  # Mypy displays "FloatSubclass"


# ChildDataClass doesn't exactly match BaseDataClass[T], but the child
# class *is* a subtype of BaseDataClass[int], which does match.

x: ChildDataClass
reveal_type(extract(x))  # Mypy displays "int"
```

For more details and examples, see the [mypy docs on generics](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html).

Comment: Thank you @Michael0x2a!  I had a misunderstanding of the intended usage of `Generic`, and that cleared me up.  I was able to use a variation of the above `extract` function to accomplish what I needed.  Thank you!